# How To Get Current Listener- Function(callback) of Element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get existing function, setted in element as listener.
Is it possible?

for example:

```
button.onclick = function() { console.log("clicked") } // setted by another library

console.log(button.someMethod()) // function() { console.log('clicked') }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find event listeners on a DOM node in JavaScript or in debugging?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/446892/how-to-find-event-listeners-on-a-dom-node-in-javascript-or-in-debugging)

Comment: In this particular case you can do `console.log(button.onclick);`. If the event listener is attached using `addEventListener`, there's no way to access the attached listener programmatically.

Comment: @Teemu Listener setted by slick.js.

Comment: I didn't notice the jQuery tag earlier. If an event is attached by jQuery, then you might find your answer from Crescent Fresh's answer in the dup suggestion Simone has linked above. Though the post is really old, I'm not sure if any of those is still valid.